# TypeORM Polymorphic Relations

Tags: typeorm

I am migrating a Laravel app to Node app using TypeORM. Has anyone been able to implement something similar to [Laravel's Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) in TypeOrm?

Example schema I am trying to reproduce:

```
export class Notification {
    id: string;
    attachable_id: number;
    attachable_type: string;
}
```

I want to be able to to have a notification.attachable relation that could be of any type. Then, ideally, I can eager load a user with their last x notifications, with the attachable on each notification.

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT:**

So I done a refactor/rewrite and put it all in a repo https://github.com/bashleigh/typeorm-polymorphic

So, I've been thinking of trying to implement something for this for a while. I had 2 days to implement something in a hurry so I made this crud thing.

```js
import {
  FindManyOptions,
  DeepPartial,
  ObjectID,
  FindConditions,
  UpdateResult,
  Repository,
  SaveOptions,
} from 'typeorm';
import { QueryDeepPartialEntity } from 'typeorm/query-builder/QueryPartialEntity';

export interface PolymorphicInterface {
  entityId: string;
  entityType: string;
}

export type PolyMorphicType<K> = PolymorphicInterface & DeepPartial<K>;

export const POLYMORPHIC_RELATIONSHIP = 'POLYMORPHIC_RELATIONSHIP';

export interface PolymorphicOptions {
  type: Function;
  parent: Function;
  property: string | Symbol;
}

export const PolyMorphic = (type: Function): PropertyDecorator => (
  target: Object,
  propertyKey: string | Symbol,
): void =>
  Reflect.defineMetadata(
    `${POLYMORPHIC_RELATIONSHIP}::${propertyKey}`,
    {
      type,
      parent: target.constructor.name,
      property: propertyKey,
    },
    target,
  );

export class PolymorphicRepository<T extends DeepPartial<T>> extends Repository<T> {
  private getMetadata(): Array<PolymorphicOptions> {
    let keys = Reflect.getMetadataKeys((this.metadata.target as Function)['prototype']);

    if (!Array.isArray(keys)) {
      return [];
    }

    keys = keys.filter((key: string) => {
      const parts = key.split('::');
      return parts[0] === POLYMORPHIC_RELATIONSHIP;
    });

    if (!keys) {
      return [];
    }

    return keys.map(
      (key: string): PolymorphicOptions =>
        Reflect.getMetadata(key, (this.metadata.target as Function)['prototype']),
    );
  }

  async find(findOptions?: FindConditions<T> | FindManyOptions<T>): Promise<T[]> {
    const polymorphicMetadata = this.getMetadata();

    if (Object.keys(polymorphicMetadata).length === 0) {
      return super.find(findOptions);
    }

    const entities = await super.find(findOptions);

    return this.hydratePolymorphicEntities(entities);
  }

  public async hydratePolymorphicEntities(entities: Array<T>): Promise<Array<T>> {
    const metadata = this.getMetadata();

    metadata.forEach(
      async (data: PolymorphicOptions): Promise<void> => {
        await Promise.all(
          entities.map(
            async (entity: T): Promise<void> => {
              const repository = this.manager.getRepository(data.type);
              const property = data.property;
              const parent = data.parent;

              if (!repository) {
                throw new Error(
                  `Repository not found for type [${
                    data.type
                  }] using property [${property}] on parent entity [${parent}]`,
                );
              }

              const morphValues = await repository.find({
                where: {
                  //@ts-ignore
                  entityId: entity.id, // TODO add type AbstractEntity
                  entityType: this.metadata.targetName,
                },
              });

              //@ts-ignore
              entity[property] = morphValues;
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    return entities;
  }

  public async update(
    criteria:
      | string
      | string[]
      | number
      | number[]
      | Date
      | Date[]
      | ObjectID
      | ObjectID[]
      | FindConditions<T>,
    partialEntity: QueryDeepPartialEntity<T>,
  ): Promise<UpdateResult> {
    const polymorphicMetadata = this.getMetadata();
    if (Object.keys(polymorphicMetadata).length === 0) {
      return super.update(criteria, partialEntity);
    }

    const result = super.update(criteria, partialEntity);

    // TODO update morphs
    throw new Error("CBA I'm very tired");

    return result;
  }

  public async save<E extends DeepPartial<T>>(
    entity: E | Array<E>,
    options?: SaveOptions & { reload: false },
  ): Promise<E & T | Array<E & T>> {
    const polymorphicMetadata = this.getMetadata();

    if (Object.keys(polymorphicMetadata).length === 0) {
      return Array.isArray(entity) ? super.save(entity, options) : super.save(entity);
    }

    const result = Array.isArray(entity)
      ? await super.save(entity, options)
      : await super.save(entity);

    Array.isArray(result)
      ? await Promise.all(result.map((res: T) => this.saveMorphs(res)))
      : await this.saveMorphs(result);

    return result;
  }

  private async saveMorphs(entity: T): Promise<void> {
    const metadata = this.getMetadata();

    await Promise.all(
      metadata.map(
        async (data: PolymorphicOptions): Promise<void> => {
          const repository: Repository<PolymorphicInterface> = this.manager.getRepository(
            data.type,
          );
          const property = data.property;
          const parent = data.parent;
          const value: Partial<PolymorphicInterface> | Array<Partial<PolymorphicInterface>> =
            //@ts-ignore
            entity[property];

          if (typeof value === 'undefined' || value === undefined) {
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
          }

          if (!repository) {
            throw new Error(
              `Repository not found for type [${
                data.type
              }] using property [${property}] on parent entity [${parent}]`,
            );
          }

          let result: Array<any> | any;

          if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            //@ts-ignore
            result = await Promise.all(
              value.map(val => {
                // @ts-ignore
                val.entityId = entity.id;
                val.entityType = this.metadata.targetName;
                return repository.save(
                  value instanceof data.type ? value : repository.create(value),
                );
              }),
            );
          } else {
            // @ts-ignore
            value.entityId = entity.id; // TODO resolve AbstractEntity for T
            value.entityType = this.metadata.targetName;

            result = await repository.save(
              value instanceof data.type ? value : repository.create(value),
            );
          }

          // @ts-ignore
          entity[property] = result;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's pretty rough but that's what I implemented to tackle this. Essentially I've implemented is my own methods to handle saving of entities that are defined within the metadata by creating my own repository.

Then you can use it like so

```js
@Entity()
export class TestEntity {
  @PolyMorphic(SomeOtherEntity)
  property: SomeOtherEntity[];
}
```

> The typings are really bad but that's only because I've had 1 days to implement this feature and I did it on the plane