# One-to-many different entity types

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

I'm learning nest.js with postgresql and I'm stuck on the one subject. Let's suppose I have three entities: entity A, B and C.

I want one of the field from the entity C to reference either to A or B.

At this moment I could set two different columns, where one refers (as one to many) to entity A, and another column to entity B.

Is there any way I could sort it out having only one column for that?

Like

```
@One-To-Many(ref to A | B)
```

Comment: Oh, the horrors JavaScript's untypedness has unleashed upon us.. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeORM Polymorphic Relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995280/typeorm-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: No! A foreign key (reference) must refer to a single unique key (or PK) in a single table. In this case you need to create 2 columns one for each needed reference. You create each as null-able column and create a check constraint to ensure (at least) one of the is null.  If your app can determine which reference is needed you can retrieve a single column with the following. `select ..., coalesce(ref_to_a, ref_to_b) ...`

Comment: I assume you are using TypeORM here.

Is A & B totally different? Does this help https://typeorm.io/#/entity-inheritance/single-table-inheritance.